# Working without Hadoop Eclipse Plugin

Tags: hadoop, eclipse-plugin

I just have a small doubt. I am working with Hadoop and map reduce . And I used yahoo-vm machine for making the map-reduce application which also comes with eclipse plugin. But when I myself tried to install hadoop separately on my computer I couldn't establish the link between eclipse and HDFS even after lot of tries. I want to know is eclipse necessary for building these applications? As I only found it useful in submitting the inputs to and receiving the output from HDFS. And even that can be automate by fs api of map redcue.

Answer (score 1):

MapReduce programs are like any other Java programs, they can be developed in notepad, vi or any of the favorite editor. IDEs like NetBeans and Eclipse make the development of the Java programs easier.

[Here](http://www.thecloudavenue.com/2012/10/debugging-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in.html) is a blog entry on developing/debugging Hadoop MapReduce programs in Eclipse without using a Hadoop plugin. Once the program has been developed/debugged in Eclipse, a jar file has to be created and then submitted to the Hadoop cluster using the `hadoop jar .....` command.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly do not need eclipse or any plugin for developing MapReduce jobs, that run on Hadoop. You can start the Hadoop deamons, copy input data onto the cluster and submit the MR job from the console. Various plugins will just help you in creation, execution and debugging of MR jobs.

In a minimal setup Eclipse (or any other IDE) can be used to write code and export the final project to a JAR. You just need to reference the hadoop jars in your project's classpath.